# Is it possible to open a browser using robotframework without adding selenium2 library? If yes, How?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am new to robotframework and trying to run a simple program to open a browser.

I tried installing selenium2 library to using pip but its failing to add the library. On further surfing I found that python 3.x versions dont support selenium.

So is there any way we can run a small program to open a browser in RF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. use a pre-built library such as Selenium2Library
2. write your own library

Since you say you can't use the pre-built library, you'll have to write your own. There is a python module for selenium, so you can create your own keywords that call the selenium functions from the selenium module.

For example, to create your own "open browser" and "go to" keywords, you might create a python library that looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

drivers = {
    "chrome": webdriver.Chrome,
    "firefox": webdriver.Firefox
}

class SeleniumKeywords:

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = None

    def open_browser(self, browser="chrome"):
        driver_class = drivers[browser]
        self.driver = driver_class()

    def go_to(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)
```

Assuming you've saved this to a file named "SeleniumKeywords.py", you can use these keywords in a test like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumKeywords

*** Test case ***
Example
    open browser    chrome
    go to    http://www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OperatingSystem`Library `Run` keywords. See [Run documentation here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Run)

Comment: That will open a browser, but the test won't be able to interact with it.